# Can I use Amazon Echo as mediation device of Device that we're making?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

We're making fitness device that connects with smartphone.

I'm wondering if I could use Amazon Echo as mediation device for our device. 
Our device should connects with Echo via bluetooth and Amazon Echo should be able to send data to our server so that user can monitoring on their smartphone without losing connection.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Echo [supports 2 Bluetooth protocols](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201727450): Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP) and Audio / Video Remote Control Profile (AVRCP) - so it can act as a BT-connected speaker, and offers voice control for connected mobiles.

Assuming from your described use case that you are employing different BT protocols, I would say that it's not possible to do what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for kind reply. !